# ssrs: "unknown collection member" when I try show or hide a rectangle based in a expression

Tags: reporting-services, reference, dataset, visibility

I get the error "unknown collection member" when I try show or hide a rectangle (contains some tables) based in this expression:

```
= First(Fields!Modalidad.Value, "ModalidadSubmodalidad")<>"Distancia"
```

Reference is generated automatically (dataset exists and field exists)

Answer (score 0):

Álvaro, try adding a tablix to your report. Link the tablix to your dataset then add your image component to the tablix.